# Browser doesn't find images from HTML when running on local host

Tags: html, django, file, http-status-code-404, localserver

I am developing my site and running on the local host now on windows computer. I want to set a background image for the page but when I run the server it throughs a message that the image is not found. The image is located in the same directory where the html is. This is a really simple thing but I am straggling with it from early morning. Looked in all the forums but nothing helped so far.

I tried changing the file path as relative/absolute. But no result. No mistake in the file name or path.

```
body {
            background-image: url("background.jpg")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
background-image: url("./background.jpg");
```

**Note:** I assume that you are using Django because of the tags, it is better to re-locate your static image files under the directory `public` or `static` which is publicly accessible from the web server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, it helped. When I moved the image to static folder it showed up. :)